# indefinite integral problem

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{7x^5}{\sqrt{5-x^3}}\mathrm dx $$

Can someone teach me about the best solution to solve this integration? 
I know I can't use substitution here. Is there a formula for this kind of integration?

I'm definitely blank about this one. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you can't use substitution?

Comment: well somehow when looking at the equation, it just didn't occur in my mind to use substitution. but yeah, I guess I was wrong. :\

Comment: Ah, just a "didn't see how". That's normal. I thought it might be something deeper, a misconception that needed rectification, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $u=x^3$:

$$7 \int dx \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{5-x^3}} = \frac{7}{3} \int d(x^3) \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{5-x^3}} = \frac{7}{3} \int du \, u (5-u)^{-1/2}$$

Now integrate by parts:

$$\frac{7}{3} \int du \, u (5-u)^{-1/2} = -\frac{14}{3} u (5-u)^{1/2} + \frac{14}{3} \int du \, (5-u)^{1/2} $$

which I assume you can take from here.

Answer (score 3):

You may consult the method [Differential Binomial](http://planetmath.org/integrationofdifferentialbinomial) to use another substitution $$5-x^3=t^2$$

Comment: Nice alternate hint! =1

Comment: Short and sweet!

Comment: @amWhy: Good night Amy. Have a colorful sleep. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use substitution to evaluate this integral. However, it requires a little algebraic manipulation of the integral first.

$\int\frac{7x^5}{\sqrt{5-x^3}}dx$

$=\int\frac{7x^5}{\sqrt{5-x^3}}\times\frac{6}{6}\ dx$

$=\frac{14}{3}\int x^3\times\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{5-x^3}}dx$

$=\frac{14}{3}\int-x^3\times\frac{-3x^2}{2\sqrt{5-x^3}}dx$

$y=\sqrt{5-x^3}$

$y^2=5-x^3$

$y^2-5=-x^3$

$dy=\frac{-3x^2}{2\sqrt{5-x^3}}dx$

After substituting we get:

$\frac{14}{3}\int\left(y^2-5\right)dy$

=$\frac{14}{3}\left(\frac{y^3}{3}-5y\right)+c$

=$\frac{14}{9}y^3-\frac{70}{3}y+c$

=$\frac{14}{9}\left(5-x^3\right)^\frac{3}{2}-\frac{70}{3}\sqrt{5-x^3}+c$